# Mongoose Validation falling for embedded document

Tags: validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this Issues schema:

```js
// Require Mongoose
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { rolesSchema } from "./roles.js";
import { storyPointSchema } from "./storyPoint.js";


// Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
/**
 * Issues Report Schema
 */
export const issuesSchema = new Schema({
    team: {
        required: true, 
        type: String,
    },
    teamRoles: {
        type: [rolesSchema],
        required: true
    },
    ticketId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    issueName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    issueType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['story', 'bug', 'task', 'sub-task', 'epic'],
        default: 'story',
        required: true
    },
    storyPoints: {
        accepted: storyPointSchema,
        committed: storyPointSchema,
        completed: storyPointSchema,
        estimated: storyPointSchema, 
        actual: storyPointSchema
    }
}, {_id: false})

/**
 * Calculate Full Name
 * Virtual for ticket assignee's full name
 */
issuesSchema.virtual('fullname').get(function () {
    let fullName = ""
    if (this.firstName && this.lastName) {
        fullName = `${this.firstName}, ${this.lastName}`
    }
    return fullName
})

export const Issues =  mongoose.model('Issues', issuesSchema)
```

Here are the two embedded document schemas:

```js
export const rolesSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type:String,
        required: true
    }
})

export const Roles =  mongoose.model('Roles', rolesSchema)

// Require Mongoose
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
/**
 * Story Point Report Schema
 */
export const storyPointSchema = new Schema([{
    storyPoint: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        enum: [0,1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
    }
}])
```

In unit testing I can get all errors that the validators throw when required is missing or wrong format data

Here is the validations errors:

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "description": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `description` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `description` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "description"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "description"
    },
    "issueName": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `issueName` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `issueName` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "issueName"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "issueName"
    },
    "ticketId": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `ticketId` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `ticketId` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "ticketId"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "ticketId"
    },
    "team": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `team` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `team` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "team"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "team"
    },
    "issueType": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "`foo` is not a valid enum value for path `issueType`.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "`foo` is not a valid enum value for path `issueType`.",
        "type": "enum",
        "enumValues": [
          "story",
          "bug",
          "task",
          "sub-task",
          "epic"
        ],
        "path": "issueType",
        "value": "foo"
      },
      "kind": "enum",
      "path": "issueType",
      "value": "foo"
    }
  },
  "_message": "Issues validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "message": "Issues validation failed: description: Path `description` is required., issueName: Path `issueName` is required., ticketId: Path `ticketId` is required., team: Path `team` is required., issueType: `foo` is not a valid enum value for path `issueType`."
```

Can you see any issues with these schemas to see why both embedded documents fail to register any errors relevant to roles or story points?

Comment: Can you share the unit test. Is this for `create` or `save` or on an update because it matters.

Comment: @jQueeny I've added the test for this. I throw the errors on the save()

Comment: Thank you I see it. The issue you encountered is that because `teamRoles` is an array of `rolesSchema` and it is a `required` field then it also means that if no array is provided during document creation then it will create an empty array. That passes validation. You have correctly identified you will need a custom validator to check that the array is not empty. When you do an update such as `findOneAndUpdate` you need to tell mongoose to `runvalidators` and it will only do this on fields that you supply in the update document.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on the `findOneAndUpdate` and have to run validators and for the insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get default or any validation working for the Story Points I had to flatten this schema ( As per Mongoose's documentation where it says embedded sub documents can be tricky as they don't actually belong to document so validation won't work.

Here is the updated storyPointSchema:

```js
// Require Mongoose
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { ActoValidator } from "../services/validators/ActoValidator.js";
const Validator = new ActoValidator();
   

// Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
/**
 * Story Point Report Schema
 */
export const storyPointSchema = new Schema({
    accepted:{
        type: Number,
        enum: [0,1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13],
    },
    committed: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [0,1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13],
    },
    completed: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [0,1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13],
    },
    estimated: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [0,1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13],

    },
    actual: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [0,1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13],
    },  
})
```

And then the issue schema is:

```js
// Require Mongoose
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { rolesSchema } from "./roles.js";
import { storyPointSchema } from "./storyPoint.js";

// Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
/**
 * Issues Report Schema
 */
export const issuesSchema = new Schema({
    team: {
        required: true, 
        type: String
    },
    teamRoles: {
        type: [rolesSchema],
        required: true
    },
    ticketId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    issueName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    issueType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['story', 'bug', 'task', 'sub-task', 'epic'],
        default: 'story',
        required: true
    },
    storyPoints: {
        type: storyPointSchema,
        required: [true,  "`the estimated story point field` is required, either 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, or 13"],
    }
}, {_id: false})

/**
 * Calculate Full Name
 * Virtual for ticket assignee's full name
 */
issuesSchema.virtual('fullname').get(function () {
    let fullName = ""
    if (this.firstName && this.lastName) {
        fullName = `${this.firstName}, ${this.lastName}`
    }
    return fullName
})
/**
 * Team roles validation for the array items
 */
issuesSchema.path('teamRoles').validate(function(teamRoles){
    if(!teamRoles){return false}
    else if(teamRoles.length === 0){return false}
    return true;
}, '`issueRole` is required. There must be at least one role added to each issue');


export const Issues =  mongoose.model('Issues', issuesSchema)
```

This now has the appropriate errors:

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "storyPoints": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "`the estimated story point field` is required, either 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, or 13",
      "properties": {
        "message": "`the estimated story point field` is required, either 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, or 13",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "storyPoints"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "storyPoints"
    },
    "description": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `description` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `description` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "description"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "description"
    },
    "issueName": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `issueName` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `issueName` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "issueName"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "issueName"
    },
    "ticketId": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `ticketId` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `ticketId` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "ticketId"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "ticketId"
    },
    "team": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `team` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `team` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "team"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "team"
    },
    "teamRoles": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "`issueRole` is required. There must be at least one role added to each issue",
      "properties": {
        "message": "`issueRole` is required. There must be at least one role added to each issue",
        "type": "user defined",
        "path": "teamRoles",
        "value": []
      },
      "kind": "user defined",
      "path": "teamRoles",
      "value": []
    }
  },
  "_message": "Issues validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "message": "Issues validation failed: storyPoints: `the estimated story point field` is required, either 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, or 13, description: Path `description` is required., issueName: Path `issueName` is required., ticketId: Path `ticketId` is required., team: Path `team` is required., teamRoles: `issueRole` is required. There must be at least one role added to each issue"
```

I hope this helps someone else :shrug"

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this validated by using this function in the issueSchema code:

```js
issuesSchema.path('teamRoles').validate(function(teamRoles){
    if(!teamRoles){return false}
    else if(teamRoles.length === 0){return false}
    return true;
}, 'There must be at least one role added to each issue');
```

Now you can see the error is included:

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "description": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `description` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `description` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "description"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "description"
    },
    "issueName": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `issueName` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `issueName` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "issueName"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "issueName"
    },
    "ticketId": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `ticketId` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `ticketId` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "ticketId"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "ticketId"
    },
    "team": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `team` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `team` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "team"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "team"
    },
    "teamRoles": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "There must be at least one role added to each issue",
      "properties": {
        "message": "There must be at least one role added to each issue",
        "type": "user defined",
        "path": "teamRoles",
        "value": []
      },
      "kind": "user defined",
      "path": "teamRoles",
      "value": []
    }
  },
  "_message": "Issues validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "message": "Issues validation failed: description: Path `description` is required., issueName: Path `issueName` is required., ticketId: Path `ticketId` is required., team: Path `team` is required., teamRoles: There must be at least one role added to each issue"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the test used to generate the error using a save():

```js
import test from 'ava';
import { Issues } from '../../models/issues.js';

test("Validate should throw all validation errors with none of the required issue fields set", async t => {
    const iS = new Issues();
    const except = async () => {
       throw new Error(await iS.save());
    }
    try {
        await except();
    } catch(e) {
        const errors = JSON.stringify(e);
        t.true(errors.includes('`description` is required.'));
        t.true(errors.includes('`issueName` is required.'));
        t.true(errors.includes('`ticketId` is required.'));
        t.true(errors.includes('`team` is required.'));
        t.true(errors.includes("`issueRole` is required. There must be at least one role added to each issue"));
        t.true(errors.includes("`the estimated story point field` is required, either 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, or 13"));
    }
});
```